# Returning error message to AJAX as well as HTTP status code

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I know how to return HTTP status codes to indicate if an AJAX call failed or succeeded using the `HttpStatusCode` and `HttpStatusCodeResult` classes, and I know how to return objects using `Json()`, but now I need to return both a `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` and a string containing the error message. I need to return the `HttpStatusCode` so the AJAX call goes to the `error` property, and can access the error message.

How would I do this in C#?

**UPDATE**
I found this bit of code:

```
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "This is an error message");
```

That works alright and I can see the response in my browser. How would I extract the message part of this to display it in an alert through jQuery?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC [HttpStatusCodeResult Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.98).aspx)

Comment: In your `$.ajax()` error handler, the error message should appear as the second argument, `textStatus`.

Comment: Got it all working now, it was `response.statusText`

Comment: Yup, that should also work.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 do you have any idea how I would do the exact same but for the `success` function in the AJAX call? The statusDescription gets sent down the wire along with the status code (200 in this case) but I'm unable to retrieve it in jQuery.

Comment: Very similar to the error handler, in your $.ajax() success handler, your `statusDescription` should appear as the second argument.

Comment: That's what I've got, but it is not picking up the description. I can see the description coming in through the networking tab so it is definitely there.

Comment: Try the third argument.

Comment: That was it - [thirdargument].statusText. Thanks.

Comment: Ah right. Args of success and error handlers line up in a different order: `function successHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`; `function errorHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. It's sometimes hard to know exactly where bespoke server-side messages are going to end up. Personally, I prefer to set custom response codes then lookup messages client-side from a code-message hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can use this line in your method,

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("Your web api path",Name = "Your web api path")]
 public HttpResponseMessage test ()
 {
     //some codes here 

 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok,[You want to return value]);
 }
```

I hope this can be help you, cheers dude,

Edit : Also you should add them in your codes, System.Web.Http; System.Net.Http and "System.Web.Http.Results;"

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this,

```
try
{
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
}
```

Edit:

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {                
              //errorThrown will have the message you sent. 
              //Also, debug and see the values in xhr object.
            }
```